# Summation involving the index multiplied by an exponential?

Tags: summation

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ia^i &= 0 + a + 2a^2 + \cdots + (n-1)a^{n-1}\\
&= \frac{a - na^n + (n-1)a^{n+1}}{(1 - a)^2}
\end{align}$$

Is there any formula for a slightly similar one?

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ia^{n-1-i} = 0 + a^{n-2} + 2a^{n-3} + \cdots + (n-1)
$$

As **Calvin Lin** suggestion:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ia^{n-1-i} &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ia^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^i = a^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^i \\
&= a^{n-1}\frac{\frac1a - n\left(\frac1a\right)^n + (n-1)\left(\frac1a\right)^{n+1}}{(1 - \frac1a)^2}\\
&= \cdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: SO, the final simplification will become $ \frac {a^n - an + n - 1} { (a-1)^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $a^{n-1 - i} = a^{n-1} \times (\frac {1}{a} )^i$.

Now apply your initial claim.

Comment: Thanks, see my edit... am I right?

Comment: @Gremo Yes, and do you know how to complete it?

Comment: I think I should use the first formula with $a = \frac1a$, right?

Comment: @Gremo Correct. Can you fill in what the final term would end up being?

Comment: Ok, it should work, see my edits. It may be simplified I think.

Comment: @Gremo You can simplify it further by multiplying the $a^{n-1}$ in, which greatly simplifies your formula. Also, your initial claim is wrong, and it shouldn't involve an $i$, and it should be a 1 instead.